# Puppeteer - Protocol Error (Page.captureScreenshot): Target closed when I try to take screenshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I am running this example code:

```
async takeScreenshot() {  
        console.log('trying take Screenshot [...]');
        let image = this.page.screenshot({fullPage: true, type: 'jpeg'});
        timeout(image, 30000)
        .then((thing) => console.log("screenshot successfull!"))
        .catch((err) => {
            if(err instanceof TimeoutError) {
                console.log(err);
                image = null;
            }
        })

        console.log('Completed!');
        return image;
    }
```

I receive the following error output:

> 0|era-moni | Error: Protocol error (Page.captureScreenshot): Target closed.
>   0|era-moni | at Session._onClosed (/home/ubuntu/project/ra-monitors/era-monitor-browser/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:209:23)
>   0|era-moni | at Connection._onClose (/home/ubuntu/project/ra-monitors/era-monitor-browser/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:116:15)
>   0|era-moni | at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>   0|era-moni | at WebSocket.emit (events.js:194:7)
>   0|era-moni | at WebSocket.emitClose (/home/ubuntu/project/ra-monitors/era-monitor-browser/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:213:10)
>   0|era-moni | at _receiver.cleanup (/home/ubuntu/project/ra-monitors/era-monitor-browser/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:195:41)
>   0|era-moni | at Receiver.cleanup (/home/ubuntu/project/ra-monitors/era-monitor-browser/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:520:15)
>   0|era-moni | at WebSocket.finalize (/home/ubuntu/project/ra-monitors/era-monitor-browser/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:195:22)
>   0|era-moni | at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>   0|era-moni | at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)

Comment: This generally happens when you're not using puppeteer with the version of Chrome it was released with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator before [`page.screenshot()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) because the function is asynchronous:

```
let image = await this.page.screenshot({
  fullPage: true,
  type: 'jpeg',
});
```